# active directory password reset

Tags: active-directory, password-reset

My question is if any user locks himself out or his password expires. Is there any safe way so that the user can self-serve a password reset? Moreover does Microsoft provides the facility that AD enrolled users can unlock their password on themselves.Any thoughts would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: There are plenty of self-service portal solutions on the web. Why don't you just hit the search engine of your choice and enter the "Active Directory self service" keywords?

Comment: Microsoft allow lockouts to be time-limited, which is as good as it gets out of the box (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277400.aspx). There are lots of self-service password reset tools out there but we don't do product recommendations here...

Answer (score 1):

There are dozens of software packages you can get that can provide self-service password reset and unlock.  They generally require a service account that is allowed to change passwords and unlock users, so they have to be well-protected, but in the grand scheme of things they don't make for an undue security problem.  If you run a google search for "self-service password reset" you're bound to find a few.  They tend to be complex and expensive, though perhaps cheaper than using a helpdesk for it.

Microsoft doesn't provide a facility, though they do publish SSPR software.

The typical case is that a user uses a kiosk account or borrows someone else's computer, and logs into a web portal; they then answer some security questions and the SSPR service unlocks their account.

Otherwise, you can just set the lockout duration via a GPO as RobM mentions in his comment; see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277400.aspx.